# iOS storyboard - view is not getting loaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm having trouble loading a detailed view from a TableView. The segue doesn't fire when a Table Cell is tapped. What can possibly be wrong? Is it the TabBarController in the bottom that is the issue?

The storyboard look like this:
(TabBarController -> TableView -> View)

[image]

Happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh :) Found it! The CellIdentifier under cellForRowAtIndexPath didn't correspond to the cell in the storyboard. Now they are equal and it works. Thanks for all help. Best regards!

Comment: You should mark this as the answer for the question so other people can find it easily.

Answer (score 2):

You have a Push segue. That makes no sense except in a navigation controller. In your situation there is nothing to push onto.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Still problem connecting the table view cell to the detail-view via segue...

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "problem connecting the table view cell to the detail-view via segue". In the screen shot, it *is* connected. It's ineffective because a push segue is impossible in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you Ctrl dragged from the tableView cell and not somewhere else on the viewController.

Comment: Yes, still no luck... Although if I put a Navigation Controller prior to the "First View Controller" I can get it to work programatically. By calling EmployeeViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EmployeeView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; from didSelectRowAtIndexPath. But it is still no beautiful storyboard solution...

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard the segue linking your firstviewcontroller to employee will not work because it does not have a navigationController. these are the steps you need in order for it to work

1. Unlink your tab with the firstviewcontroller
2. Drag and drop new navigationcontroller and delete the provided rootview.
3. Ctrl drag your navigationcontroller to firstviewcontroller and pick rootViewController as relationship
4. Link your tab to navigationcontroller not firstviewcontroller
5. try and see if it works.

Comment: There is a short cut for the first 4 steps, you can just select the firstviewcontroller and then in the Editor menu choose Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck getting the detail-view to load via a segue. Storyboard now: http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/1344/storyboard2.png

Comment: Are my outlets to the TableView disturbing the segue in some way? But I have to populate the TableView in some way, hmm...

Comment: As I said earlier if I call: EmployeeViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EmployeeView"]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; from didSelectRowAtIndexPath it works but shouldn't I be able to load the view without using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Apples SimpleDrillDown example is not using didSelectRowAtIndexPath...  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html